# Select 2nd and 3rd element from each triplet of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set of 6 elements and I would like to filter by every second and third element so I want to have elements 2, 3, 5 and 6. I've tried `.filter(':nth-child(2n+1)'));` but obviously that filters the 2, 4, and 6.

The other way I was trying was to remove elements 1 and 4, but I couldn't find a jQuery function that was the opposite of filter that would remove the elements from the set.

Comment: Can you explain how "every 2n and 3n" does include #5, but does not include #4? Did you mean _"I want to have elements 2, 3, 4, and 6"_?

Comment: I agree with Phrogz that your question is not stated correctly.  It sounds to me like what you really want to do is skip the first element, and then every third element thereafter.  In other words, you want to skip every element that has n%1=1.

Comment: @Phrogz No, I think ephemient answer explains what I wanted better. "the 2nd and 3rd out of every group of 3"

Comment: There's been a bunch of discussion on what I actually wanted. If somebody has a better recommendation for what I can title this question, please see accepted answer and let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by your example, I don't think you actually want 2n and 3n.  You want the 2nd and 3rd out of every group of 3?  Then either one of these should work:

```
.filter(':nth-child(3n+2), :nth-child(3n+3)'));
.filter(':not(:nth-child(3n+1))');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
.filter(':not(:nth-child(1),:nth-child(4))')
```

http://jsbin.com/owosuw/2/edit#source

Comment: btw if you really need selection for every 2n and 3n element you should use .filter(':nth-child(2n),:nth-child(3n)')

Comment: @VladMinaev Thanks for your answer, but I feel like ephemient's answer was a bit better I could use it for larger sets than 6, so I gave it the correct answer to them. Still giving you a +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `filter` with a function (that takes a single parameter which is the zero-based number of the matched element):

```
$('div').filter( function(n) { return n%3!=0 } )
```

See my JSFiddle proof-of-concept here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4c4Re/

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do it with only one `nth-child`. I don't know what you want to do, but if you want to give it a style or class or event or something in that category you can give it them all and remove it from the 1th and the 4th:

```
$('div').addClass('red');

$('div:nth-child(3n+1)').removeClass('red');
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/gnbMH/

---

You could also use two `nth-child`s to get it work:

```
$('div:nth-child(3n+2)').addClass('red');
$('div:nth-child(3n+3)').addClass('red');
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/gnbMH/1/

---

You also could combine to the two `nth-child`s and then you get something like this:

```
var elems = $('div:nth-child(3n+2)');
$('div:nth-child(3n+3)').each(function(i,elem) {
    elems.push(elem);
});

$(elems).addClass('red');
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/gnbMH/2/

Comment: In the future, don't leave the crucial answering code off in a JSFiddle: put it in the answer, too! :)

Comment: @Phrogz thank you. I normally do that, but I don't know why not now... I edited the comment

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:not(:nth-child(3n+1))`.. Something like `.filter(':not(:nth-child(3n+1))').`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/LgSBJ/1/)